# ¿Cual es la mejor manera de almacenar llaves primarias desde no SQL a SQL?

Tags: sqlite, nosql

Actualmente obtengo datos desde una base de datos **no SQL** como **MongoDB**

### ejemplo

base de datos de **Mascotas** que cada mascota tiene dentro una lista **Vacunas**

**Ejemplo estructura**

```
{
    "nombre": "perro1",
    "raza"  : "Pitbull",
    "vacunas":[
        {
            "tipoVacuna" :"tipo",
            "fecha":"fecha"
        }
    ]
}
```

para pasar esto a **SQL** utilizo el **id** que ya genera **MongoDB**, el cual tiene varios caracteres por lo tanto genero tablas con la siguiente estructura para almacenar la información recibida.

```
Tabla Perros
idPerro TEXT,
nombre TEXT,
raza  TEXT,

Tabla Vacunas
idVacuna INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
tipoVacuna TEXT,
fecha DATE,

Tabla PerrosVacunas
idPerro TEXT,
idVacuna INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
```

Se me ocurrió que seria mejor almacenar el **idPerro** como llave primaria

Pero al no ser experto con base de datos investigue que no es muy optimo almacenar tipo `TEXT` como `PRIMARY KEY`ya que las consultas de **`JOIN`** con muchos registros no seria muy optimo ya que es probable que la base de datos cresca hasta una posible cantidad mas de 800 registros.

Entonces me interesa saber cual seria la mejor manera de almacenar esta información para que las consultas sean mas optimas.

Comment: bueno cuando inicie fue por que los datos se envían de regreso a **MongoDB** para actualizar la base que ya se encuentra ahi, pero no pense que en lo optimo de no crear **PK**

Comment: aunque tenes razon con lo de las claves alfanumericas, una base con 800 datos se maneja rapido hasta en excel.

Comment: aparte de eso.. la base es incremental? es una sola vez? como haces la importacion? cambiar el id no deberia ser problema en ninguno de los casos

Comment: Al ser un dispositivo móvil, entonces no afectaría que tenga la estructura como en el ejemplo que pronpongo? sin una **PK** las consultas `JOIN` no tendrian problemas ?

Comment: Bueno los datos en mongo de los perros pueden variar pero en el movil lo unico que podria variar serian las vacunas probablemente

Comment: La PK no tiene nada que ver con los joins. Vos podes hacer join por el campo que quieras. La PK es para tener un indice en la tabla.

Comment: La pregunta fue si vas a importar los datos de un lado a otro o que vas a hacer con los mismos..

Comment: Los datos los pasare de noSQL a SQL y viceversa por lo tanto me interesa tener la mejor estructura para ambas partes y almacenarlas de forma correcta con la PK

Comment: usa las claves que ya tenes entonces.. por 800 registros, crear otra tabla para mantener las estructuras acordes no parece tener ningun sentido. 800 registros no son una cantidad suficiente. Es mas.. casi que lo podrias hacer en memoria.

Comment: ok entonces usar la estructura que tengo actual no me genera ningún problema para el rendimiento de un dispositivo movil? y por lo que intento hacer a lo mucho tendría 4,500 registro aproximadamente pero de inicio se cargan entre 800 y 900 registros,

Comment: @gbianchi mi intención es almacenar de la mejor manera las pk para que no genere problemas mas adelante, de igual manera poder utilizar un método de búsqueda eficiente en el móvil, donde los resultados puede que se sincronicen con otros  móviles.

Comment: Yo lo testearia, pero a priori no deberias tener ningun problema